# The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found error in Jekin build

Tags: jenkins, asp.net-core, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline

I am very new to CI/CD. I'm now trying to integrate Jekins, xunit test, asp.net core and gitlab.

I created a new freestyle project and linked to my gitlab. after that, I configured the MSBuild from global tool configuration. after that, I configured the Build session like that [image: that]. When I start building, I got this [image: error]. I have already tried to add path variable MSBuildSDKsPath to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.500\Sdks but it doesn't work. pls help me, Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSBUILD throws error: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257393/msbuild-throws-error-the-sdk-microsoft-net-sdk-specified-could-not-be-found)

Comment: I have tried with that solution but it doesn’t work

Comment: for which user did you set that variable? If your CI tool run as a service, please ensure the variable is set for all users.

Comment: I put under the system path variable