# Unable to build the ASP.Net Core 7 in azure devops pipeline (CI)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

Unable to build the ASP.Net Core 7 in azure devops pipeline (CI), Using Classic pipeline and ASP.net core template

Error message :

##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5)
: Error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 7.0.
Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 7.0.

Comment: Hi @devendar, could you kindly provide the relevant task definition in your issue to help us better understand you question? Thanks.

Comment: You need to edit the question to include your complete YAML file.

Answer (score 2):

Add a task to install the .NET version that you need (you can change 7.x to something more specific)

```
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Use .NET Core SDK 7.x'
    inputs:
      packageType: sdk
      version: '7.x'
      installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
```

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-dotnet-v2?view=azure-pipelines)

Comment: Hi I have tried YAML script as above, I am getting the below  error message               
[error]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5):
 Error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\ExPro Core\ExProModel.Model.Server\obj\project.assets.json' not found.                                                                                                                        
                                                                                   2) Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

Comment: And I assume you have followed the instruction and ran `dotnet restore`?!

Comment: - task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

Comment: - task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

Comment: restore and build scripts are above

Comment: please paste your entire relevant pipeline code in your question post

Answer (score 1):

We faced this same issue in upgrading to .NET 7 on our self hosted agents, and despite adding the `UseDotNet@2` as described by silent, we still ended up with failures referencing various 6.0.x SDK targets.

The issue ended up being resolved through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339086/685760) answer. It was due to a previous install of .NET 6 and the variable `MSBuildSDKsPath`. If you have self hosted agents, check the "Capabilities" of the agent to show the variable itself.

Failing that, check the value of that through the pipeline itself with a step like;

```
      - script: set
        displayName: show all env vars
```

An example snippet of our ci-pipeline.yaml that worked is as follows. Important notes are **MSBuildSDKsPath** overriding whatever environment variable is set on the agent to reflect the location of the newly installed .NET 7 SDK;

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
    exclude:
    - develop
    - main

variables:
  - name: solution
    value: '**/*.sln'  
  - name: BuildConfiguration
    value: 'Release'
  - name: MSBuildSDKsPath
    value: C:\agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\sdk\7.0.102\Sdks

jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      name: 'Modern'
    workspace:
      clean: all

    steps:
      - script: set
        displayName: show all env vars

      - checkout: self
        persistCredentials: true

      - task: UseDotNet@2
        displayName: 'Use .NET 7.x'
        inputs:
          packageType: 'sdk'
          version: 7.x
          performMultiLevelLookup: true
          includePreviewVersions: false
          installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
```