# Visual Studio 2022 Solution Explorer is empty

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When I create a new console project and enable the "Don't use top-level statements" option, the project is created, but there is nothing in Solution Explorer and I can't run the program. On macOS there is no such problem. On Windows 11 there is.  [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhNCf.png)

Comment: Is this question (or anyone of the answer it has) helping:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912433/visual-studio-solution-explorer-not-showing-files-and-folders ?

Comment: This question has been asked many times now for Visual Studio 2022.  Such as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75665941/visual-studio-2022-solution-does-not-see-project?rq=2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76005258/solution-explorer-of-visual-studio-2022-not-updated-after-creating-an-asp-net-co?rq=2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74386006/why-my-latest-version-visual-studio-2022-does-not-contain-any-project-under-the but no clear solution I feel like.  Only person I saw that got it working had to reinstall it 3 times.

Comment: Only solvable when someone with the problem solves, and describes, this problem. but since no clear solution seems to exist....    I know Visual Studio creates some logfiles in the directory `%TEMP%VSLogs` (but there are 93 files in the on my computer, so no clue where to start searching...., and I do not have this problem 

Answer (score 0):

you need to right click on Solution and in menu, click on Add>Existingproject and select your Project.cs . its will Ok :)