# The specified SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I want to open a project in visual studio 2022 I get the following message "One or more projects of the solution did not load correctly. See the output window for more information" and in the output window appears the following: C:\Users\USER\Downloads\ProgramacionCapas\CapaNegocio\CapaNegocio.csproj :error: The specified SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" could not be found.    C:\Users\USER\Downloads\ProgramacionCapas\CapaNegocio\CapaNegocio.csproj

Comment: Have you checked if [existing/releated answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257393/msbuild-throws-error-the-sdk-microsoft-net-sdk-specified-could-not-be-found) help?

Comment: I have reviewed but I have no idea where to put the commands that indicate there

Answer (score 0):

**Option One:**

1. Please execute "dotnet --info" in cmd, please remember the Base Path.

[image]

2. Open the environment variable, find the variable named MSBuildSdksPath, and change its path to the Base Path found in the previous step (the last \ do not, for example, what I want to add is C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100)

**Option Two:**

1. Confirm your project and the applicable sdk for the dependencies referenced in the project
2. Make sure your computer has installed the corresponding sdk and runtime, if not installed, you can download the corresponding sdk at https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet