# Visual Studio does not let me create or open Winui 3 projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, winui-3

I am currently having an issue with Visual Studio, which does not let me open or create any winui 3 projects. Opening a winui 3 project will result in this error:

> The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.

Attempting to create a winui 3 project will result in:

> Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
> [image]

Do note that the repository originated from a different computer and has never switched the .Net SDK version.

What I've tried so far:

1. Reinstalling & repairing Visual Studio
2. Reinstalling the .Net 6 SDK

What my .csproj file looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>Clankboard</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win10-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="ShellPage.xaml" />
    <None Remove="SoundboardPage.xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.3.230602002" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.756" />
    <Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- 
    Defining the "Msix" ProjectCapability here allows the Single-project MSIX Packaging
    Tools extension to be activated for this project even if the Windows App SDK Nuget
    package has not yet been restored.
  -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(DisableMsixProjectCapabilityAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <ProjectCapability Include="Msix" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Update="SoundboardPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Update="ShellPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- 
    Defining the "HasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject" property here allows the Solution 
    Explorer "Package and Publish" context menu entry to be enabled for this project even if 
    the Windows App SDK Nuget package has not yet been restored.
  -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DisableHasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <HasPackageAndPublishMenu>true</HasPackageAndPublishMenu>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Definitely looks like a setup problem (I've the almost exact same csproj). You want to concentrate on the "The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found." error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257393/msbuild-throws-error-the-sdk-microsoft-net-sdk-specified-could-not-be-found

Comment: Make sure [the requirements for the Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/set-up-your-development-environment?tabs=cs-vs-community%2Ccpp-vs-community%2Cvs-2022-17-1-a%2Cvs-2022-17-1-b) are all installed.

Comment: Have you tried a fresh start with VS preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the end the issue was happening due to .Net itself. It only detected x86 .Net SDKs.

It was fixed by moving the `C:\Program Files\dotnet` env variable above the `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet` env variable.